# Best practices while designing reference data model in DynamoDb

Tags: amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I need to design a database with one main functional data table and thinking to keep all reference data in separate table. I can keep the both type of data in the same table but for the sake of clarity want to keep them separate. My access pattern for reference data is simple as get all lookup data. I have following doubts on the same:

1. If I need to get all reference data I need to keep the PK same for all reference entity types. e.g. a movie database may have refence entities like Genre, Categories, Age Groups etc. These all have PK as REF_Data and SK as GENRE, CATEGORY, AGE_GROUP etc. But in that case my table will have only one PK, which seems absurd design to me or maybe not a very good use of nosql. Also I do not want to keep PK as different entity names and scan the table as it does not perform well.
2. Second question I am trying to answer myself is, what is the best practice, whether to create 1 item for each reference entity and keep all data in one attribute as JSON document. e.g. 1 item for all genres and add all genres in a JSON document in single attribute say DATA.
   OR should I keep GENRE as SK and create multiple items and access with composite key(PK+SK) for 1 type of reference data to get many items in 1 query. I am keeping in mind that 1 item in Dynamo has a limit of 400Kb max. What is the best way in terms of price and performance.

Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: This is covered in the DynamoDB guide https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-relational-modeling.html

Comment: When you write PK and SK, are you referring to DynamoDB partition key and sort key?

Comment: Yes @jarmod. I should have elaborated that earlier.